# After the DS9 finale what happens to the Jem'hadar and what assurances do the Federation have that the Dominion won't attack again?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion, shape-shifter, jemhadar

ST Deep Space Nine "What You Leave Behind":

> ODO: All I ask is that you Link with me.
>
> GARAK: I'm warning you, Odo.
>
> ODO: Nerys.
>
> KIRA: Garak, put down your weapon.
>
> GARAK: I don't think so.
>
> KIRA: I said, put it down. (Odo does the Link and she is cured.)
>
> GARAK: Move aside, Odo.
>
> ODO: That won't be necessary. Will it?
>
> FOUNDER: If you will stand aside, **I'll order the Jem'Hadar to cease
>   fire.**
>
> GARAK: I suggest we secure her in a containment field.
>
> ODO: **Don't worry, Garak. She won't try to escape. She's agreed to
>   stand trial and accept responsibility for what she's done.**

ST Deep Space Nine "What You Leave Behind":

> (The surrender documents are being signed.)
>
> FOUNDER: **The war between the Dominion and the Federation Alliance is
>   now over.**
>
> ROSS: Four hundred years ago, a victorious general spoke the following
>   words at the end of another costly war. Today the guns are silent. A
>   great tragedy has ended. We have known the bitterness of defeat and
>   the exultation of triumph. From both we have learned there can be no
>   going back. We must go forward to preserve in peace what we've won in
>   war.  (Douglas MacArthur, WW2. The Founder is escorted from the table.)
>
> FOUNDER: It's up to you now, Odo.

So Odo heals the founder and agrees to heal the Great Link. He's been in the Great Link before and they already know how he feels about "solids" and they manipulated him into almost assassinating Gowron as well as taking away his shapeshifting powers.

I'm not sure exactly what the founder is going on trial for, but it wasn't her alone, and declaring war on somebody isn't a crime. If it was the entire Great Link should be on trial.

This didn't seem like a very good deal for the Federation unless there is something I don't know about.

In any event, what happens to the Jem'hadar, the Dominion, all of their forces, and what guarantees are there that the Great Link won't attack again or manipulate Odo again?

Any out of universe explanations, writers notes, guides, companions, etc. or in-canon stuff is welcomed. If there isn't anything then EU stuff is also welcome.

Comment: The Founders committed a wide variety of atrocities and war crimes during the Dominion War, notably the bombing of civilians on Cardassia (several billion dead) and the occupation of various Federation worlds without any real justification other than to cause terror.

Comment: @Richard Isn't all war kind of like that. It's territorial, bigotry, political, etc. Lots of people get killed senselessly, etc. The Nazi's did war crimes which I think is quite obvious. Stalin did war crimes. But did Italy commit war crimes in WWII? Did Japan? Did the allied powers? I'm not sure what exactly constitutes putting somebody on trial. I think when it gets to concentration camps, experimenting on people, etc. that I think is obvious. Destroying the Cardassian rebellion is just war as ugly as it is. And at the end of the show it said 700 million total dead on both sides in the war.

Comment: Shakespeare could still say that “All is fair in love and war”, but since the 19th century, legal rules were developped regarding what you could or could not do in war. – Interestingly, those crimes that you seem to be prepared to accept as war crimes aren’t; they were committed (mostly) _during_ a war, but not as part of the war. They are _crimes against humanity_.

Comment: @JMFB No, all war is not like that.  And also, I'm not sure this is a great place for such philosophical discussions.

Comment: “...what assurances do the Federation have that the Dominion won't attack again?” They signed a *treaty* bro. With a *pen*. You don’t just welch on a treaty.

Comment: This is two separate questions. One about Jemhadar soldiers. Another about whether the Dominion will attack again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this comes down to a fundamental understanding of Odo's abilities to see the Founder's thoughts. At the end we see him linking with her, at which point at appears that she lets down all of her mental defences, providing Odo with a complete overview of her thinking. He then speaks on her behalf;

> **ODO:** *Don't worry, Garak. She won't try to escape. She's agreed to stand trial and accept responsibility for what she's done.*

Given that he no longer has censored access, it's reasonable to assume that his statement that the Founders are willing to sue for peace is an honourable one. Presumably this is also accompanied by a cessation of all hostilities, everywhere. Even if they were trying to trick Odo, this would put them at such a massive tactical disadvantage as to not be worth it.

---

As to why the Federation think that the peace will hold, it's down to the fact that [one Founder can speak for all Founders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfrOm3LuHBI).

> **Odo:** *When you return to The Link, what will become of the entity I'm
>   talking to right now?*
>
> **Founder:** *The drop becomes the ocean.* - <sub><sup>[DS9: Behind the Lines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Behind_the_Lines_(episode))</sup></sub>

---

As to "what happens next", that's a [whole 'nother book series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_relaunch).

Comment: There's related material in [STO: Facility 4028](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Mission:_Facility_4028). I'd wager latinum that it conflicts with the novels, though.

Answer (score 2):

In Episode 4 season 7, Weyoun #7 tries to recruit Odo to replace the female Founder to bring peace to the galaxy, which is a hint as to how the season will end.  He gives all kinds of reasons why this would work.

When the female Changeling surrenders, Odo tells Kira he will go back to the Great Link and remain there.  The Great Link will be grateful that Odo saved them from the disease; they will give their support to Odo as the new "ruler" of the Founders.  He said to Kira in the final episode that he will convince them to change.

The older Founder will stand trial for her actions and be sentenced.  As Odo heads back to the Gamma quadrant, he will take all the Vorta and Jem'hadar with him.  The new prophet Sisko will let them through and also prevent the Jem'hadar from coming through to the Alpha quadrant again.

With Odo as ruler of the Gamma Quadrant and the Sisko as one of the prophets governing the wormhole, that's the Federation's assurance that the Dominion will never attack again.

Answer (score 1):

Also earlier in the war the female changling states that bringing Odo homes is worth more than the entire alpha quadrant. Surrendering the war in exchange for Odo’s return seems something that they would consider a bargain.

Comment: Do you know when earlier was? Same episode, different? Could you [edit] this in?

Comment: If you add a quote from an episode, it will really enhance your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You have also got to remember that in *Star Trek: Enterprise*, they were discovered by Captain Archer, the planet they lived on was a Rogue planet, that was close to what would become Federation territory when Archer realized the people were hunting sentient life forms for sport that could change shape.

Think of the benefit and view you would have if your home planet was a rogue planet.  The first shapeshifter took a form of a girl from Archer’s memory, to ask for help (fictional character from a story).  Archer gave them the masking agent to evade the hunters.  It’s possible the rogue planet could have traveled through Federation controlled space during the 23, 24 century and reached the Gamma Quadrant by the time Deep Space 9 came along.

It was also suggested that Kirk even met a Changeling in the movie where he was sent to the Klingon Prison Rar Pentia(spell check needed)23rd Century.  Star Trek: DS9 24 century Remember, what the Changelings said at the beginning when Odo finally discovered his people, we used to be explorers and went out and explored the universe to gain knowledge, but they found out because they where so different many of the worlds hunted them and persecuted them, and drove them out of their worlds.  The Changings forgot the one favor that Archer did for them, but they didn't recognize the people humans that helped them the most because the Federation didn't exist when Archer met them 22 century.  However, Odo has the Federations complete historical database in his mind and the Changelings in the link will remember Archer’s masking agent.

The Changlings lost their way, because they got bitter from the treatment they received from all the other worlds they visited to gain knowledge to bring back home, they decided to found the Dominion to bring order to what they perceive as a threat, which was a chaotic universe, and at the time of the Dominion War the rogue planet was in the Gamma Quadrants far away from the Federation and the only organization that would most likely protect them.  In the exact same episode that Odo found his people she mentioned that we are the leaders of the Dominion, we control the destiny of many worlds, as what you control can't hurt you.

The Founders didn't recognize the species that Archer came from and if they did the war could have been avoided.  The Shapeshifters planet went through federation Klingon and Romulan space during the time of the 22, 23, 24 century it would be in the gamma quadrant by the time odo met his people, and the wormhole was discovered.
The founders in that episode the said out of bitterness from the way they have been treated throughout the Universe that they saw it was their job to give order to the Galaxy that they perceived as a threat from the Solids.  In one of the Star Trek DS9 episodes of the Dominion War someone asks Wayon to tell the story of how the Vorta Got to be a great power in the Dominion, what the Vorta where like Ape like Tree drawling people and one family protected a changling from the mob, the changling than promised the vorta they will become a great power in a new Empire.

The Changling kept his word, and they became a great power the enforcers of order.  The answer is quite simple the Jem'hadar and the Vorta are cloned by the founders as needed.  It is possible that when Odo came back to the Great Link his experience with the solids could maybe change the views of the other Changelings and encourage the Dominion to be a more Democratic and Just Empire.  this would likely cause the founders to stop breeding the Jem'hadar and the Vorta.  Odo is the main guarantee that the Federation won't attack them and is the main guarantee that the changlings will honor the agreement.  It is also possible the Dominion worlds that was conquer would likely be offered membership.  However, the Dominion did loose territory, the Caredasian and Breen territory was divided into chunks by the Federation Alliance.  So the Jem'hadar would most likely eventually die out as Odo would not continue to breed them.  They may continue to breed the vorta for their unique Administration abilities.  In Star Trek Deep Space 9 Video game it states, that All the Gamma Quadrant Jem'hadar either went back to the Gamma Quadrant or killed themselves.  The alphas were abandoned and left to fend for themselves until the white ran out, they became mercenaries.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked - what happened to the Jem'Hadar.

Comment: Nor does it tell us how the Federation can trust that the Dominion won't attack again.

Comment: It answers the insurance that the founders will never attack the federation and that the federation will protect them.

Comment: I added more information that answers the question better.

Comment: You are mistaken. The shapeshifters found in the Alpha Quadrant aren't the same as the Gamma Quadrant '*Changelings*'; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35118/enterpise-s01e18-rogue-planet-is-the-planet-the-same-one-the-changelings-are-fr

Comment: Not really, because we don't know how fast things travel around our galaxy flying past solar systems at high speeds.  It is possible based on the non solar system fly by of a asteroid that the rogue planet that was in the alpha quadrant at the time could have traveled into the Gamma Quadrant at the speed of rotation of the Milky way Galaxy.  The rogue planet from Star Trek Enterprise and Star Trek DS9 look the same.  The trees are the same the insects are the same, they glow at night.

Answer (score -3):

The Federation develops Kravocel-white, a replacement for Ketracel-white, that provides for the nutritional needs of the Jem'Hadar, without encouraging aggression.  The Jem'Hadar that did not immediately commit suicide upon surrender, where relocated to a Federation Prison where they were re-educated.  Results were mixed and only a small percentage of Jem'Hadar ever successfully integrate into society and gain a new but limited freedom.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Where did you get this information from?  It will go a long way in improving your answer if you were to cite some source for this